# On the uniform convergence of the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series $ \ \large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (nx)}{n} \ $

(i) converges uniformly on $ \ [2 \pi-5,5] \ $

(ii) converges uniformly on $ [2 \pi-10,10] \ $

(iii) converges uniformly on $ \ \left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \right] \ $

(iv) does not converge uniformly .

**Answer:**

Here we can use Dirichlet's test.

Take $ \ \ a_n=\frac{1}{n} \ $ and $ b_n=\sin (nx) \ $

where $ a_n \ $ is monotonically decreasing .

and

$ \left| \sum_{n=0}^{k} \sin(nx)\right | =\left| \sin (x)+ \sin (2x)+\dots+ \sin (kx) \right| \ \leq \csc \left(\frac{x}{2}\right ) < \infty \ \ \text{if} \ x \neq 0,\pm 2\pi,\pm 4\pi, \dots $

Thus the series converges uniformly 0n $ \ \left[\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3 \pi}{2} \right] \ $

The option (i) is wrong because $ [5, 2 \pi-5]=[5, 1.14] \ $ , which is absurd .

Thus option (iii) is true.

**But I need better reason why the other options are not correct .**

Comment: Where does the inequality $\sin x+\sin2x+\cdots+\sin kx\leqslant\csc\left(\frac x2\right)$ come from?

Comment: It is actually absolute value.  $ | \sin x+\sin 2x+...........+\sin kx | =| \frac{\cos (x/2)- \cos (n+1/2) x}{2 \sin (x/2)} |  \leq  cosec (x/2) \ $

Comment: Concerning (i), one could argue that $[5,2\pi - 5] = \varnothing$, and every sequence of functions vacuously converges uniformly on $\varnothing$. The same for (ii).

Comment: option (i) and (ii) should be incorrect because only one answer can be correct and option (iii) is already correct

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dirichlet's test is pretty useful, but in dealing with *pointwise* convergence only.

It is well known that
$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n} $$
is the Fourier series of a sawtooth wave, a $2\pi$-periodic function which equals $\frac{\pi-x}{2}$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$. We may notice that $f(x)$ is not continuous at the origin, since $f(0)=0$ but $\lim_{x\to 0^\pm}f(x)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$ (do you need a formal proof of this fact? If this is the case, please notify me in the comments). The same applies at every element of $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. A uniformly convergent series of continuous functions is convergent to a continuous function, hence the given Fourier series cannot be uniformly convergent over any closed interval containing $[2\pi k-\varepsilon,2\pi k+\varepsilon]$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon>0$. On the other hand the convergence **is** uniform over any compact set with a positive distance from $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$.